# Why am I not getting a sapphire dragon in dragonvale?

Tags: dragonvale

Ive bred my mountain dragon with my rain dragon at least 10 times now and still havent gotten a sapphire dragon. Both are at level 10 and Im on level 20. How long is it going to take and what am I doing wrong??

Comment: breeding a sapphire question is by chance you cant expect to get it just because you bred those two 10 times...

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out on the [Gemstone Dragons](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Gemstone_Dragons) wiki entry, all gemstone dragons have a *very* low chance of being bred. Breeding them on the epic breeding isle improves those odds *slightly* but ten failures is well within the expected bounds.

(Some math: Even if the chance for a gemstone is as high as 10% -- and while I don't know the actual percentage I expect it's even lower your chance of missing ten times in ten shots would be 35%, give or take. If it's 5%, that chance would increase to 60%.)